# How do I get a view reference row number to know where the user clicked on the texxtviews in Android

Tags: android, textview

`public void refereshBill(boolean all)
{
int rowTemp = 0 ;

```
   if (all == false )
       rowTemp = rowIndex ;


   for (int row  = rowTemp ; row <= rowIndex  ; row++)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
       {
           TextView editText = new TextView(this);
           GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
           param.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;//ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

           // String id_text = String.valueOf(rowIndex) + String.valueOf(i) ;
           // int id_int = Integer.valueOf(id_text);
           // editText.set

           if (i == 2)
               param.width = 70;    // Qualnity GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
           else if (i == 3)
               param.width = 100;   //Rate//-25
           else if (i == 4)
               param.width = 80;   //Discount-20
           else if (i == 5)
               param.width = 140;   // Amount-20
           else if (i == 6)
               param.width = 40;    // %
           else if (i == 7)
               param.width = 75;  // cTax
           else if (i == 8)
               param.width = 75;  // sTax
           else if (i == 9)
               param.width = 180;  // Ttoal amount
           else
               param.width = 45 + (i * 250);

           param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(1 + row);
           param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(i);
           param.setMargins((5), 5, 0, 0);
           ///////editText.setTextColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
           editText.setTextSize(12);
           editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
           editText.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
           editText.setLayoutParams(param);
           /////// editText.setId(Integer.parseInt("i"));
           editText.setText(BillArray[row][i]);
           Glyout.addView(editText);
       }
   }
   showBillTotal();
```

}`

I have program creates a bunch of rows of textviews with different columns. as and when the user add an item for the bill .So if the user wants to change the quantiy at any point of time and clicks  on item  name .Can i get a reference view .so that i can process further.How can it be done for addition or deletion of a row , or update its values. Each row is billed item details, like item name ,rate ,etc
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCwpJ.jpg)Image shows different rows of items added into the bill as and when Clerck adds new item number ,it gets added to the list .
Thanks
naveen

Answer (score 0):

I think for a task like this just use ListView *instead* of TextView